# Setting up broker url

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I would like some help here. All I want is to add Celery and RabbitMQ to my django project. I followed this tutorial [Celery - First Step with Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). and It was able to work. However how could I customize this setup?

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
```

How can I change `guest` as a real given userId and password? Where should I configure it like: `amqp://userid:1234@sample.com:5672`

Comment: Do you install broker?

Comment: @Jinje yes I installed rabbitmq-server

Comment: just add `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'` to `settings.py` of Django settings

Comment: so there's no need to set up userid and password?

Comment: yes, please try. If you want to set user then you may follow @Nitheesh Answer. Just paste the settings to django settings.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html#broker-rabbitmq):

To use Celery we need to create a RabbitMQ user, a virtual host and allow that user access to that virtual host:

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl add_user myuser mypassword
$ sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost myvhost
$ sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags myuser mytag 
$ sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost myuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

P.S. For virtual host, you can always just give **/** in place of **myvhost** if required.